# Importing data from multiple text files into Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, text

I might have a question about VBA and Excel Macros. The thing that I need to do is to import data (actually integer values) from multiple text files that have random generated names (for example 12345678.txt, 8654321.txt, etc.) but which are stored in the same folder (let's call it Data folder) to excel into a column.

The problem that I face is that I have the same name for the measured values (called MVA) that are repeating over and over in the text files. I don't need all the data from the text files, only some specific rows of these MVA (for the example below let's say that I need only the MVA number for the "LED 01 Intensity" which is 6250 to be stored in a new cell in Excel. And I need to get that value that comes after "LED 01 Intensity" in the MVA row from 10 multiple text files (with random names that I don't know) to be stored each one in separate cells in Excel (from A1 to A10).

Example_____________________________________________________________________

Name: 153588.txt

Date: 14.05.2016

Name of product: Electronic Device 01

CHECK TEST

Resistance 101

MVA: 2 Ohm

MAX: 5 Ohm

MIN: 0 Ohm

PASS

LED 01 Intensity

MVA: 6250

MAX: 10000

MIN: 5000

PASS

---

I need a lot of these MVA values to be stored in Excel for analysis and I need to get an idea if this problem can be solved with VBA. If you can offer me some help to create a macro for this I would be thankful (I have basic knowledge of programming but I'm a beginner in VBA).

Comment: Files in a directory can be easily read with VBA no matter what they are named - using filesystemobject or even Dir() command.  Then many different ways to solve the parsing. I would likely import each file into a worksheet then read the content to search certain text (LED 01 Intensity) then pick the values where the certain text found . This is all about parsing and it is possible with VBA and also Excel sheet structure help. One can only give you advices after seeing how you attempted to solve it and also file structures are important to find out how to deal with inconsistencies if any.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is there any code you can share or a tutorial I can start from? I'm new to VBA and I might need a bit of help to understand the parsing algorithm.

Comment: Please give me an exact sample content, then I can write a sample code for you later today. It might help to start unless you receive an answer by then.

Comment: ok so as I mentionted in the first example I need to copy the MVA value under "Led 01 Intensity" from hundreds of text files every one of it into a new cell in Excel. You said that you would likely import each file into a worksheet and then search the text and then do the parsing and copy that value into a new cell (are you sure this method works for hundreds of text files while keeping things organized?) If you can start from what I give you so far can you create a code. For the sample content let's say we have 5 text files with the same structure I mentioned in the eg. just different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I promised for. It is actually not only sample but **actual** code that you need according the descriptions you provided.

Please note I wrote it according to the sample file you provided - means that it **might** fail with different text file structures.

You will notice there is a **settings section** at the beginning. That's where you setup what needs to be given to the code.

It won't be a big impact for only hundreds of text files for your system considering the sample file - perhaps will work and finish in seconds. However screen updating might be disabled in the code during the code execution. See ScreenUpdating property of Excel Application object if you notice a real big system slowness.

I am hoping to give you some good start for the VBA, so I tried to use many methods and commented a lot to explain what we are doing in each step. For example, using the first worksheet as results worksheet in the newly created workbook but creating a new worksheet for the temporary worksheet. There is a reason for this: every new workbook is created with at least one worksheet but it might be also the only one worksheet according to the Excel settings in that computer. However, even those part could be designed different by getting the number of the worksheets first and delete the unnecessary ones and keep only 2 then use those instead creating a new one.

Shortly - there are many different ways to accomplish the same task - like in many other programming languages. For example, I used QueryTable to import data into the worksheet then used Find method to find out if it has the values I needed. I didn't have to do this, I could have instead put the all information in a string variable and make the search in the string! Or by using another method, or another.

Finally this is supposed to be what you need. And I hope it gives you a good start. To make this code work: Create a new workbook -> goto VBA -> Use menu and Insert->Module -> Copy and paste the following code into the right pane opened in the editor. Change the necessary variables in the settings area at the beginning in the sub procedure (likely only the path variable) and hit F5 to run the code.

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wrk As Workbook
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim shtResult As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim fndSection As Range
Dim fndValue As Range
Dim data As QueryTable

Dim strFile
Dim strPath As String
Dim strExt As String
Dim strSection As String
Dim strValue As String

    ' ======== BEGIN SETTINGS ========
    ' Define the files path - note there is a last backslash
    strPath = "C:\Users\smozgur\Desktop\files\"
    ' Define file extension
    strExt = "*.txt"

    ' Section to be find
    strSection = "Led 01 Intensity"
    ' Cell value to be find after section
    strValue = "MVA:"
    ' ======== END SETTINGS ========


    ' Create a new workbook to not mess with existing
    Set wrk = Application.Workbooks.Add
    With wrk
        ' Use first (or only) worksheet to store results
        Set shtResult = .Worksheets(1)
        ' Create temp worksheet for reading text files
        Set shtSource = .Worksheets.Add
    End With

    ' Name the Results worksheet
    ' and put search value to indicate it in results
    With shtResult
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = strValue
        .name = "Results"
    End With

    ' Make file search with the given path & extension information
    strFile = Dir(strPath & strExt, vbNormal)

    ' Dir function returns the first file name
    ' with the given extension in the given path
    ' if it is empty string then it means "no more file returned"
    Do Until strFile = ""
        ' Create a query table buffer by using the file reference
        ' in the temp worksheet starting from cell A1
        Set data = shtSource.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strPath & strFile, Destination:=shtSource.Cells(1, 1))
        ' Set up query table import properties
        With data
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True

            ' Finally retrieve data from the file
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        ' Now the file content is in the temp worksheet as rows

        ' Find the section string in the data as Cell
        Set fndSection = data.ResultRange.Find(strSection)
        If Not fndSection Is Nothing Then
            ' If section is found then search for the Value Name AFTER found section
            Set fndValue = data.ResultRange.Find(strValue, fndSection)
            If Not fndValue Is Nothing Then
                ' If Value Name is found then put it into the next available cell in Results worksheet
                ' by removing the Value Name, so it will be the value itself
                shtResult.Cells(shtResult.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Replace(fndValue, strValue, "")
            End If
        End If
        With data
            ' Clear the query table range
            .ResultRange.Delete
            ' Delete the query table so we can recreate it for the next file
            .Delete
        End With

        ' Search for the next file meets the given path and extension criteria
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    ' Delete the temporary worksheet
    ' Make it silent disabling Application Alerts about deleting the worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    shtSource.Delete
    ' Enable Application Alerts back
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Enjoy VBA programming!

==================================

*** EDIT FOR MULTIPLE SECTIONS ***

Following code handles multiple sections in the source files.

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wrk As Workbook
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim shtResult As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim fndSection As Range
Dim fndNextSection As Range
Dim fndValue As Range
Dim data As QueryTable

Dim strFile
Dim strPath As String
Dim strExt As String
Dim strSection As String
Dim strSections
Dim strValue As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim indFileNames As Boolean

    ' ======== BEGIN SETTINGS ========
    ' Define the files path - note there is a last backslash
    strPath = "C:\Users\smozgur\Desktop\files\"
    ' Define file extension
    strExt = "*.txt"

    ' Sections to be find
    strSections = Array("Led 01 Intensity", _
                        "Led 02 Intensity", _
                        "Led 03 Intensity", _
                        "Led 04 Intensity", _
                        "Led 05 Intensity")

    ' Cell value to be find after section
    strValue = "MVA:"
    ' Indicate file names in the output?
    indFileNames = True
    ' ======== END SETTINGS ========


    ' Create a new workbook to not mess with existing
    Set wrk = Application.Workbooks.Add
    With wrk
        ' Use first (or only) worksheet to store results
        Set shtResult = .Worksheets(1)
        ' Create temp worksheet for reading text files
        Set shtSource = .Worksheets.Add
    End With

    ' Name the Results worksheet
    ' and put section headers to indicate their columns
    With shtResult
        With .Cells(1).Resize(, UBound(strSections) + 1)
            .Value = strSections
            .Resize(, UBound(strSections) + 1).Font.Bold = True
        End With
        If indFileNames = True Then
            With .Cells(1, UBound(strSections) + 3)
                .Value = "NOTES"
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        End If
        .name = "Results"
    End With

    ' Make file search with given information
    strFile = Dir(strPath & strExt, vbNormal)

    ' Dir function returns the first file name
    ' with the given extension in the given path
    ' if it is empty string then it means "no more file returned"
    Do Until strFile = ""
        ' Create a query table buffer by using the file reference
        ' in the temp worksheet starting from cell A1
        Set data = shtSource.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strPath & strFile, Destination:=shtSource.Cells(1, 1))
        ' Set up query table import properties
        With data
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True

            ' Finally retrieve data from the file
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        ' Now the file content is in the temp worksheet as rows

        ' Loop through requested sections
        For i = 0 To UBound(strSections)
            ' Find the section string in the data as Cell
            Set fndSection = data.ResultRange.Find(strSections(i))
            If Not fndSection Is Nothing Then
                ' If section is found then search for the Value Name AFTER found section
                Set fndValue = data.ResultRange.Find(strValue, fndSection)
                If Not fndValue Is Nothing Then
                    ' What if value doesn't exist in this section but it finds the next value in the next section
                    ' We have to avoid that unless we are certainly sure each section MUST have the value
                    If i < UBound(strSections) Then
                        Set fndNextSection = data.ResultRange.Find(strSections(i + 1), fndSection)
                    Else
                        Set fndNextSection = shtSource.Cells(shtSource.Rows.Count)
                    End If

                    ' Next available cell in the Results worksheet
                    Set rng = shtResult.Cells(shtResult.Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

                    ' Only use the value if found value belongs to the section
                    If fndValue.Row < fndNextSection.Row Then
                        ' If Value Name is found then put it into the next available cell in Results worksheet
                        ' by removing the Value Name, so it will be the value itself
                        rng.Value = Replace(fndValue, strValue, "")
                    Else
                        rng.Value = "N/A"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If indFileNames = True Then
            ' Let's indicate which file we got this values
            Set rng = shtResult.Cells(shtResult.Rows.Count, UBound(strSections) + 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            rng.Value = strFile
        End If

        With data
            ' Clear the query table range
            .ResultRange.Delete
            ' Delete the query table so we can recreate it for the next file
            .Delete
        End With

        ' Search for the next file meets the given path and extension criteria
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    ' Autofit columns in the Results worksheet
    shtResult.Columns.AutoFit

    ' Delete the temporary worksheet
    ' Make it silent disabling Application Alerts about deleting the worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    shtSource.Delete
    ' Enable Application Alerts back
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW! You're amazing!! thank you very much for the code & the detailed explanations (it really helps me as a beginner). I played a bit with your macro today and I searched for values and it works perfectly just the way I wanted but only for a single column . I would like to ask if In case I need to search multiple LEDs values at once is it ok just to define more strSections and strValues ?  And I would also like to ask you if it's possible to define the column name with the MVA values as the coresponding text i'm searching for (led01,02,03,etc intensity)? Again thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Confirm one thing please: when you say multiple, you are not talking about finding the same value, I.e. Second MVA in the same document, right? Because it would require changing the algorithm, however otherwise I'll show you how to make it worked efficiently with arrays in VBA in the same code. Please let me know. Note: I forgot to say something important: please don't run any code you'll get online from other people without making sure what it does first since VBA (like any other macro or programming language) can be really dangerous in right hands.

Comment: @VenomX sent you an update above but forgot to add your name. Just in case you didn't get the notification. Please let me know.

Comment: I'll take that advice seriously. It might be a problem then because when i say multiple I mean more than one LED inside a text file, each LED having the coresponding MVA value. I thought that by showing you the example I will make myself a bit more clear about what I'm trying to do and I didn't want to overcomplicate it. Is there any possible way of doing this by slightly changing the algorithm ? or do you know a more simple method with VBA and Excel ? I think that you understood the problem I have really well and once again I am very thankful for your help.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/81ofz0o5t/ have a look at this so you can understand it better

Comment: @VenomX try to post a more generic data file. Or send me at my user name at gmail if it is too big, even a few different files better. I might not make the changes right away as I am away from my computer until tomorrow but as soon as I can. If you followed the code and understood how things work win VBA with excel object model then you'll notice the changes will make you go faster in VBA.

Comment: @VenomX I just saw the link and I assume it is sample files. Ok.

Comment: @VenomX nope, it is image, not helping, I already understand what you need. Please try to provide more real sample files so I can work with it. Let me explain why I also asked you this same thing before: because if you sent me more content file then I would have seen the second sections and built the logic accordingly in the first place.

Comment: Alright then I will send you a few text files on your e-mail if you'll give it to me. Thank you

Comment: @VenomX I edited my answer and added a revised code for your request. Hope it helps. Let me know please.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm. This is exactly what I needed the macro to do. Another thing that might help me is modifying the number of components that I'm searching for - in this case we had 5 LED Intensity values. What if I need let's say 10 or 20 ? And what happens if the MVA is not the first row after the component name (but it's always the second or the third row)? Can it be easily modified for let's say "n" components and MVA being the "m" number of row after the component name? UPDATE: I did a test and the MVA: row number doesn't matter as far as i noticed

Comment: MVA doesn't have to be second item, as long as it is listed after the section name and before the next section name - I wrote the code considering that (a bit experienced on unmentioned points :) ). Regarding new sections: you can simply add new section names into the strSections array variable and good to go. No need to modify the code other than adding the new section names. Glad to hear it helps. You can accept the answer and close this question. Let me know if/when you hit any wall with the macro.

Comment: Yes, it works if I add new section names. I upvoted the answer. I definitely accept it ! It's perfect. thank you so much for your help and for everything ! Wish you all the best.