# How to export specific values from TXT into Excel?

Tags: excel, text, automation

I work with a software that generates it's measurement results into TXT files. 
Each time I measure something it saves the results into a uniquely named TXT.

**Example.TXT**

```
Date: 2017.01.23.    
Sample ID:  ASD-123-YXZ    
Maximum Runs: 7    
Flow Purge:  10.0 min
```

And I have an excel sheet in which I have to copy the results manually. It contains all measurements. From example: I have made 10 different measurements and got 10 different TXT's. From these files I copy/paste the values I need into ONE excel. Like column A1 contains the dates etc. for all txt's.

My goal is to automate this task. Do you have any advice how to accomplish that?

ps: sorry for my English

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing data from multiple text files into Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220488/importing-data-from-multiple-text-files-into-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

This is a short C# program that import each TXT file from a folder and export all of them into Excel file. It used [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) Excel library for exporting the Excel file:

```
ExcelDocument excel = new ExcelDocument();

//This is a folder where all TXT files are stored
System.IO.DirectoryInfo folder = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderTXTfiles);

//Import each TXT file and create a sheet from each one
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
{
     try
     {
           ExcelDocument txtExcel = new ExcelDocument();
           txtExcel.easy_LoadCSVFile(file.FullName);//or easy_LoadTXTFile
           String sheetName = file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.IndexOf(".txt"));
           if (sheetName.Length > 31)
           {
                sheetName = sheetName.Substring(0, 31);
           }
           ExcelWorksheet sheet = (ExcelWorksheet)txtExcel.easy_getSheetAt(0);
           sheet.setSheetName(sheetName);
           excel.easy_addWorksheet(sheet);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
     }
}

//Export Excel file    
excel.easy_WriteXLSXFile(folder.FullName + "\\" + "Excel.xlsx");
```