# Import selected data from multiple text files into single excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate some help with this. I've tried code from similar examples but I have not been able to bend existing solutions to my will...

My problem:
I have hundreds of textfiles with analysis results where I need specific data extracted into a single excel worksheet for further processing.

If you look at the example txt: 
"Hemoglobin: [20.3 - 37.7] mg/dL    IL Threshold: 500.00000000  User Threshold: 70.00000000
" (way down in the file).
I need this information copied to a worksheet, in space and tab separated columns I guess, to get the interval numbers in separate cells for further processing.

For all files in the same folder I want this information extracted and put in the same worksheet. (A bonus would be to have the filename copied to a cell prior or after the information for traceability).

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220488/importing-data-from-multiple-text-files-into-excel-vba) example from stackoverflow to get the whole line extracted, but I'm stuck on getting the interval numbers into separate cells.

Very thankful for any help with this.

/anna

```
************************ DR INTERMEDIATE RESULTS REPORT v2.2 ************************

RAW DATA REPORT

#Date-Of-Report: 2017-10-03 13:57:55
#SampleID: 081394260022
#Test: APTT-SS  Test Release: 7.7
#Type: Patient
#AquisitionMode: Standard
Not a Shadow/Parent Not a Paired Test
Report generated by: bma    [23]

INTERMEDIATE VALUES FOR SINGLE DETERMINATION (PRIMARY WAVELENGTH)

#Wavelength: 671nm-Red  #SampleRate: 1
#ORUChannel: 0  #ORUHead: 0
#AMErrors: 0
#Concentration: 0   #Determination: 0   Delay Points: 160   

ORU Blank Value: 0.93298700


#Time   AM_Data Flags   Raw Normalized  Deriv1  Deriv2  
-----   ------- -----   --- ----------  ------  ------  
    ...

#End


JOB DATA
Job UID: <1506076487_192670>    Sample UID:  <1506075157_192475>    Test UID:  <1409942324_1953>
Material UID:  <0_0>    Quality Control UID: <0_0>
#SampleID: 081394260022 #Test: APTT-SS  #Type   Test Release: 7.7
Wavelength: 671nm-Red   EndOfDelay - Time:  16.00000000 Acquisition Time: 120.00000000  #AquisitionMode Standard
#Type: Patient

Lot Type: Unknown lot   Lot Status: Active Lot

Calibration UID: <0_0> Finish Date 
Master Calibration UID: <0_0> Finish Date 
Paired Master UID: <0_0> Finish Date 
Rerun Master UID: <0_0> Finish Date 
NormalPoolPlasma UID: <0_0> Finish Date 

Tracking materials: 2
Material: APTT-SS   Mat Def UID: <1409942324_1792>  Vial: <1505888472_171077>
    Type: Reagent   Lot ID: N1065660    Expiration Date: 2018-10-31 23:59:59

Material: APTT-SS CaCl2 Mat Def UID: <1409942324_1793>  Vial: <1505975574_181431>
    Type: Reagent   Lot ID: N1065543    Expiration Date: 2019-10-31 23:59:59


User Revision:  Order Date: 2017-09-22 12:34:47 Finish Date: 
Priority: Normal    Job Status: Complete    Persistent Job Status: Complete
Track: 09   Is CTS: 0   Is TFH: 0   Slot: 5 AM: 1   Rack Area: Sample   Position: 0
Highest Error: --
Added by: user
Display Clot Curves as Primary Wavelength: Normalized   Y Axis Setup    [0.000 - 3000.000]  AutoScale   Enabled
    Smooth with degree: 11  5   3   
Normalization is: Normalize using absorbance

Completed Date: 2017-09-22 12:40:46 Calculated Date: 2017-09-22 12:40:46
Validated Date: 2017-09-22 12:40:46 Verifier: bma
Result Status   OK  Validation Status: OK
Upload Status: Uploaded Print Status: Not printed


Precision: 3    
Test Range: [-999999.999 - 999999.999]
NPP Mode:   User input valueNormal Pool Value: Result: 0.00000000   s
    Normal Range: Disabled
    Test Range: [16.000 - 120.000]

Calibration:    Result Status   Undefined
Calibrated Delta Check: 0.00000000
Overall Calibration (all segments) Result Status    FAILED Segment Cut Off: 0.00000000
Calibration curve results computed with following axis configuration
    Calibration Results along X axis, Measured Results along Y axis
Overall Calibration (all segments)
 *** Calibration Results used in Parallelism ***
    with x transformation:  X=X
    with Y transformation:  Y=Y
Result Status   Undefined
this model failed estimation due to Indetermination error



HIL Results
    TestCode: APTT-SS   Completed Date: 2017-09-22 12:38:52 Status: OK
    Hemoglobin: [20.3 - 37.7] mg/dL IL Threshold: 500.00000000  User Threshold: 70.00000000
    Bilirubin: [0.6 - 1.2] mg/dL    IL Threshold: 26.00000000   User Threshold: Disabled
    Lipemia: [44.8 - 54.7] mAbs IL Threshold: 4886.00000000 User Threshold: Disabled


Concentration: 1    Concentration: 100.00000000 Liquid Name     Target: 100.00000000
Determination: 1    Completed Date: 2017-09-22 12:40:46
Primary Wavelength  Determination Wavelength Results
MeasuredResultResult: 29.10000000   s
    Normal Range: [-999999.900 - 999999.900]
    Test Range: [16.000 - 120.000]

UpperClotPoint: Has not been established    ClotPoint: 131.00000000

Result: 29.10000000 s
    Normal Range: [-999999.900 - 999999.900]
    Test Range: [16.000 - 120.000]


First deriv peak max: 207.76553401  Second deriv peak max: 849.28084124 Second deriv peak min: -408.66120386

Primary Wavelength  Concentration Wavelength Results

MeasuredResult  %CV:    Failed
Result: 29.10000000 s
    Normal Range: [-999999.900 - 999999.900]
    Test Range: [16.000 - 120.000]

Result: 29.10000000 s
    Normal Range: [-999999.900 - 999999.900]
    Test Range: [16.000 - 120.000]

Calibration Result Result: Undefined    
    Normal Range: Disabled
    Test Range: Disabled


REPORTABLE RESULTS FOR JOB

Highest Error: --


Result: 29.10000000 s
    Normal Range: [-999999.900 - 999999.900]
    Test Range: [16.000 - 120.000]


Errors and Warnings:
    NONE
```

Comment: This would be a good task for Regular Expressions (regex) to extract specific data. See https://regex101.com/r/0BMJQK/1 for an example of how a pattern could look like. There are also [many examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Regular+Expressions+VBA+excel) on Stack Overflow how to use Regular Expressions in VBA.

Comment: Or perhaps the `Find` method will serve your purposes. Either way, have a go, post your code if you get stuck and you can get specific advice.