# Reading a specific part of a text line using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the 827th line from a text file to write in a cell. There are a lot of files like this so that is why I am trying to use a macro. The text file looks like this

```
"Drag Convergence"
"Iterations" "cd"
1     7.74776e-01
2     6.51021e-01
3     5.58885e-01
.....
824     3.57617e-01
825     3.57617e-01
```

I just want to write the number "3.57617e-01" to a cell. I can do the cell arrangement myself but I did not have a good way to read that value and then write it to a cell lets say (1,1)

My file location is

```
strFile = "D:\Analiz\Database\NACA63220_" & Mach(k) & Alpha(j) & Letter(i) & ".txt"
```

What I did was using

```
strPath = "D:\Analiz\Database\"
strExt = ".txt"
strSection = "Lift Convergence"
strValue = "825     "

With shtResult
     .Cells(1,1).Value = strValue
End With

strFile = "D:\Analiz\Database\NACA63220_" & Mach(k) & Alpha(j) & Letter(i) & ".txt"

Set data=shtSource.QueryTables.Add(Connection:TEXT;" & strPath & strFile, Destination:=shtSource.Cells(1, 1))

With data
.TextFileStartRow = 1
.TextFileParseType = xkDelimited
.TextFileVonsecutiveDelimeter = False
.TextFileTabDelimiter = False
.Text FileSemicolonDelimiter = False
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True

.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Set fndSection = data.ResultRange.Find(strSection)
Set fndValue = data.ResultRange.Find(strValue, fndSection)
shtResult.Cells(shtResult.Rows.Count, 1).End(xkUp).Offset(1).Value = Replace(findValue, strValue, "")
```

This gives a run time error 1004, and when I press debug, it highlights the line with .Refresh BackgroundQuery

I did not put everything here like dimensioning etc because I have to use my phone to access this site so I am writing all of the codes with my phone again.

Edit: I added more lines, the problem highlights the Refresh Background Query line when I press debug.
I was actually trying to implement this by tweaking to my problem:

[Importing data from multiple text files into Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220488/importing-data-from-multiple-text-files-into-excel-vba)

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question. What is the current result and how do you want that result to be different?

Comment: I was not able to get a result at all. When I try to run it it gives run-time error '1004'. As the result I would like to get the value I pointed out from the example file and just write it in a cell.

Comment: Does the column iterations exist in the file?  You could use a query to drive your table, instead of the entire file, `where iterations=827`  WHat is your error and where does it happen.

Comment: I just added more lines and wrote something at bottom, edit part. I took the code from another stack overflow question but was not able to make it fit to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function to read specific line from textfile

```
    ' read specific line no.
    ' RESULT : searched text (string)
    Function ReadLine(FilePath, LineNumber) As String
    Dim i As Integer, count As Long
    Dim strLine As String
    i = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Input As #i
    count = 0

    While Not EOF(i)
        Line Input #i, strLine
        count = count + 1
        If count = LineNumber Then
            ReadLine = strLine
            Close #i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Wend

Close i
End Function
```

have you got any others problem with implementation? please clarify

the second code is for string splitting

```
     Function BreakString(a As String, pos As Integer) As String
     Dim WrdArray() As String
     WrdArray() = Split(a, "     ")
     BreakString = WrdArray(pos)
     End Function

Dim Text, Part1, Part2 As String
Text = "827     3.57617e-01"
Part1 = BreakString(CStr(Text), 0)
Part2 = BreakString(CStr(Text), 1)
```

Comment: The thing is, I need to omit the number 827 and 5 spaces, and just get the number that comes after this. I think your code gets the whole line?

Comment: Yes, whole line, you could use simple condition like : If ReadLine StartWith 827, Split by [space], 1, and finally Trim the string.. Could cast to Double (CDbl)

Comment: I understood your code but could you give an example about the trimming thing? I checked it but it cuts the last part of the code or not?

Comment: see my next post

Comment: Yep by putting these together, it worked! Thank you and I accepted this one as the answer. I think if you add your second code to this one, it would be better for other people that might find this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you not to use standard VBA file handling for this matter: VBA file handling starts reading a file from the first line, and continues, line by line, until it reaches the line you're looking for. As you need to read 827 lines, you are waiting 827 time too long for your response.

Instead of this, I'd try to find a commandline, which can handle this, something like:

```
tail -1 <filename> >output.txt (or head -827 <filename> | tail -1 >output.txt)
```

Translate this into Excel VBA, something like:

```
Shell "tail -f <filename> >output.txt" //pseudo-code
```

And then, use VBA standard text handling for reading output.txt.

Comment: I will check this too, the above solution worked so I will accept that as an answer, but thanks.